# Onchange not working if changes made from JavaScript function for Combobox

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Onchange function can't invoke from combobox, if the change made from  JavaScript function. Say for example I have three combobox participant, margin group, Account Code. If I change participant will call a function, margin group values added based on participant value. **Account Code values added based on margin group.** The problem rise when  Margin Group changes made by JavaScript function not by user. Is there any event for this situation?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Then in that case, you can to trigger the event manually. If you are using jQuery, you can use the trigger event to trigger the change event http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Alternatively, you can define the function for onChange call backs then manually call that function. The following are some psudo code.

```
AccountCode.onChange
  call account_code_changed()
end

Marin Group.onChange 
  # do something else
  call account_code_changed() directly
end
```